# jQuery .append() <tr> and <td> add's <td> outside of <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using input to gather information in a form and then building it into a table dynamically which both examples do fine, but when I added a remove button I noticed that the `<td>`'s were outside the `<tr>` with the first example. I believe that's because the  auto closes, but if I add it into the 2nd append so it shows as ""... it puts the first td on it's own row and the rest are on a new row.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it. Having it all in one long line works, but I dislike how messy my code looks.

```js
var $tbodyAppend = $('table > tbody:last-child');
// this puts the <td>'s outside the tr, but looks correct on the page
$tbodyAppend.append("<tr>");
$tbodyAppend.append("<td><span></span></td>");
$tbodyAppend.append("<td><span></span></td>");
$tbodyAppend.append("<td><span></span></td>");

// this puts the <td>'s in the <tr>
$tbodyAppend.append("<tr><td><span></span></td><td><span></span></td><td><span></span></td>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span>column 1</span></th>
    <th><span>column 2</span></th>
    <th><span>column 3</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <!-- want jQuery to append here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're outside because you're putting them outside. Not closing the `<tr>` doesn't mean that you didn't append an entire `tr` element.

Instead, append a single string using template literals.

```
var $tbodyAppend = $("table > tbody:last-child").append(`
  <tr>
    <td><span> ${variableHere} </span></td>
    <td><span></span></td>
    <td><span></span></td>
  <tr><td><span></span></td><td><span></span></td><td><span></span></td>
`);
```

Not only does this allow multi-line strings, but it will also let you use string interpolation to insert any expression values into the string if needed.

Comment: I'm inserting variables from the input fields into <td> variableHere </td>. I have been using + to concat it all. Will this work when inserting variables as well? Sorry I should've made that clear.

Comment: @Hunter: The string interpolation syntax will handle it. I'll add an example to the code.

Comment: When I tried that I get an Uncaught SyntaxError Invalid or unexpected token. jshint says Unterminated string literal and JSX expressions must have one parent element.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, if you have any more advice, I'd be grateful. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Hunter: Not sure. Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/L9xLub69/ Won't work in older browsers though. You'll need to transpile the code into ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to wrong DOM element when appending. Try this way.

```
var $tbodyAppend = $('tbody');
$tbodyAppend.append("<tr><td><span></span></td><td><span></span></td><td<span</span></td></tr>");
```